# xpages copy field value to other application

Tags: xpages

Is there a simple way to copy the value from an inputText  to a field inside a Xpage ( document content ) from other application via a `<xp:link>`?

I know how to redirect the user to the respective URL, but how can I pass the value for the receiver xpage / field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a parameter to URL like `?value=theValue`.

In target XPages you can access the parameter with `param.value` in SSJS code.

Comment: the receiver field is already binded to a field ( from the xsp datasource ) ... Can I access in this case the parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can replace the value in data source with `document1.replaceItemValue("yourField", param.value)` in beforePageLoad event.

Comment: And the URL should be like: http://server/XP.nsf/doc.xsp?action=newDocument&?value=theValue ?

Comment: No, use only one time "?" and then "&" as parameter delimiter like `server/XP.nsf/doc.xsp?action=newDocument&value=theValue`

Comment: My receiver field has the default value: defaultValue="#{javascript:param.value}" , and the url is something like this: http://server/XP.nsf/doc.xsp?action=newDocument&value=test, but still no result after redirecting the URL... Should I use some quotes for the transmitted value ?

Comment: defaultValue doesn't work because there is already a value set from document1 even it is empty. Use the replaceItemValue() in beforePageLoad event like I wrote in my comment before.

Comment: It seems it works :) BTW, if I open the doc.xsp normally, without any ?value=test parameter, the code from beforePageLoad event is executed, but the default field will be null, considering the fact that param.value = "" , right?

Comment: Yes, frame replaceItemValue() with `if (param.value) { ... }`

Comment: If we have more than 10 values to pass another application. Is it possible to pass value by using any scope environment? applicationScope, sessionScope or etc.

Comment: If both XPages are in the same .nsf then sessionScope is a good option for data exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a two-stage process: 1) pass it to somewhere the other page can retrieve it from. 2) Retrieve it when the other page loads and put it into the inputText.

Using server-side code (SSJS, Java) you can't pass a value for retrieval outside the current NSF unless you take advantage of an OSGi plugin (aka extension library). Each NSF is its own JSF application and is not aware of any other. Something like the OpenNTF Domino API has the concept of a serverScope, which would allow it to be stored there.

If your NSF doesn't use an extension library that provides a server scoped map, the only option is to pass it in URL parameters (encoding the value accordingly). The receiving page will then need to retrieve the value from the URL parameter on page load, decode the value and put it in the inputText. That can either be done with `getComponent("inputText1").setValue()` or, better practice, put into the datasource it's bound to, e.g. if the inputText is bound to the value `#{document1.field1}` then use `document1.replaceItemValue("field1", myParamValue)`